# Java TextArea and JLabel on a seperate line

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextarea

I have a layout problem. I'd like the `JTextArea` to be on the line above the `Jlabel`. If I run the current code, the `JTextArea` appears on the *same* line (on the left) as the JLabel (on the right). I have no clue how to fix this, since I can't convert it to two `Jlabels` or anything else for that matter. I specifically must implement this using a `JTextArea` and a `Jlabel`.

Thanks in advance.

```
this.AddTextArea1("127.0.0.1:3500", 1, 22 "Black");
this.createLabel(label2);

public void AddTextArea1(String text, int rows, int columns, String color) {
    JTextArea textarea1 = new JTextArea(text,rows,columns);
    if (color == "Gray") {
       textarea1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
    } else if (color == "Black") {
       textarea1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }
    panel.add(textarea1);
}

public void createLabel(String text){
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
    panel.add(label);
}
```

Comment: Look at BoxLayout

Comment: Side note: change `color == "Black"` to `color.equals(“Black”)`

Comment: Look at `GridLayout`, look at `GridBagLayout`, look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: -- or better: yet, `color.equalsIgnoreCase("black")`

Comment: Thanks for the responds. Since I am using a FlowLayout for all the classes I hoped the was an easy solution, but I guess now I have to implement the borderlayout for this part.

Comment: As a alternative you could use [MigLayout](http://miglayout.com/) . It is not part of the JDK, so you have to add it as a dependency. But i like to work with it when it comes to design a more complex UI (ok...your request is not complex but it might gets complex in the future).

Answer (score 0):

While other layouts might not always locking 2 components in the same column or row, you may consider to use JSplitPane.

```
private javax.swing.JSplitPane jSplitPane1;

jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(446); //sample width, please adjust
jSplitPane1.setDividerSize(0);

jSplitPane1.setLeftComponent(label);
jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(textarea1);
```